# How to create/update Rails date_select params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The javascript function enables the field with the checkbox, but then the value for the field isn't passed to the controller on submit. How can I fix this?

```
<%= f.label :texture_date, "Texture" %>
<%= f.date_select( :texture_date, 
  { :order => [:month, :day], disabled: true }, 
  { class: 'texture_date' }) %>
<%= check_box_tag :texture_date_enable, '' %>

$(document).on('change','#texture_date_enable', function(){  
  $("select.texture_date").prop('disabled', !this.checked);
});
```

UPDATE: The param is actually going to the controller, but it isn't updating.  It's also sending :texture_date_enable as a param, which isn't wanted.

Here's what the params look like in the log:

```
"texture_date(2i)"=>"2", "texture_date(3i)"=>"2"
```

Is the (2i) and (3i) causing problems?

UPDATE:

Full params.  Notice that "Date received in shop" is passing, but this field was enabled on page load.  All the other date fields are optional, and they aren't getting updated.

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"rg8yJ4hKAOeUEKytzDq3mc5SwPdnNQitFOlK6VrfU2p49JmX9Ipu0M+dT2GWO+LttS+BMy+5nJ5WXGBo63yh9A==", "ticket"=>{"date_received_in_shop(2i)"=>"2", "date_received_in_shop(3i)"=>"2", "date_received_in_shop(1i)"=>"2015", "job_number"=>"", "customer"=>"", "address1"=>"", "city"=>"", "manufacturing_location"=>"D", "mapsco_page"=>"", "builder_contact"=>"", "builder_contact_phone"=>"", "salesman"=>"", "draftsman"=>"", "door_style"=>"", "door_manufacturer"=>"D", "insulation_and_or_inspection"=>"None", "texture_date(2i)"=>"2", "texture_date(3i)"=>"2", "notes"=>"", "block_up_for_floor"=>"0"}, "texture_date_enable"=>"", "commit"=>"Update Ticket", "id"=>"20"}
```

Comment: please send screenshot of params. Also is the naming correct and is the params permitted?

Comment: the `(2i)` and `(3i)` are how Rails passes the parts of dates around.

Comment: Will you look at my params hash? Why is the "date received in shop" working but not the ones that I enabled on the form?

Comment: yes the params are permitted and the naming is correct

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the hidden/disabled Year field.  By adding the year field to the other enabled inputs, the form worked as expected.